# Flutter Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm developing flutter app and I added firebase auth to project. 
And it's running fine, but when app loads up console says this.
Is this normal behavior? Thank you!

```
    5.4.1 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003]
 The default Firebase app has not yet been configured.
 Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift)
 to your application initialization.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [configuration of IOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup#configure_ios) in flutter. Then create a [`Podfile`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#add_the_sdk), inside that file add the following libraries to be able to use Firebase auth:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
```

Then go to this path `flutterApp\ios\Runner\AppDelegate.m` and import and configure firebase:

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"

@import Firebase; // new

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

//configure firebase
[FIRApp configure]; // new

[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  }

@end
```

Comment: Thank you Peter but even if I got firebase package in flutter, do I have to do this steps?

Comment: Yes, you need to configure it also for IOS, do u have the `GoogleService-Info.plist` in the ios part?

Comment: Oh I didn't know that thank you so much!! Yes I have that in Runner subfolder.

Comment: okay please go to this path `flutterAppName\ios\Runner\AppDelegate.m` and import and configure firebase

Comment: @PeterHaddad I wonder how you figured out to use the ios documentation to implement this into flutter? It is not written in any other documentation. This solution helps with the error of the question, but there are still google sign-in errors in my project. To install google sign-in using the firebase ios documentation -- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin -- is a tedious project which requires intermediate skills in objective-c -- only to use flutter. Do you have any idea of how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I had faced a similar issue when i was using firebase, turned out I hadn't included configuration in Info.plist in the iOS module